# cookie not expires after set

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to check cookie is exist or nor and then create a cookie 'login_time' with expire tire 2 minutes.now cookie was created but not expired .now cookie is alive even after 5 mins

```
if((document.cookie.indexOf('login_time=')<0)){
                var expiry = new Date();
                expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime() + 120);  
                document.cookie = 'login_time=yes; expires=' + expiry;

    }
```

Comment: Your code appears to renew the cookie whenever it expires...

Comment: Note that getTime() returns milliseconds, not seconds

Answer (score 1):

This will expire cookie.

```
if((document.cookie.indexOf('login_time=')<0)){
var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 2;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 document.cookie = 'login_time=yes; expires=' + date ; 
}
//3.5* 60 * 1000 = 1 minute and 30 seconds
```

Comment: still not expire